# I have added custom field in sales_order_grid but cannot retrieve data by getData( )

Tags: magento2, order-grid, order-comment

I need to get order comment in order grid, but cannot retrieve data by `getData( )`

### Upgrade script

```
<?php

namespace vender\Ordercomment\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->salesSetupFactory = $salesSetupFactory;       
    }



    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();



        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2') < 0) {
            $setup->startSetup();

            /** @var \Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetup $salesInstaller */
            $salesInstaller = $this->salesSetupFactory->create(['resourceName' => 'sales_setup', 'setup' => $setup]);


            $salesInstaller->addAttribute(
                'order',
                'order_comment',
                ['type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT, 'length' => '64k', 'nullable' => true, 'grid' => true]
            );

            $setup->endSetup();



        }

    }

}
```

### Controller

```
namespace vender\Customoption\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function __construct(Context $context
                               ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $order2 = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();

        foreach ($order2 as $t) {
            echo $t->getOrderComment();
        }

        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's bad practice to use the Object Manager in client code (i.e. Your code). Use Dependency Injection instead. That's what it's there for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `order_comment` attribute to your order collection.